# Is there os native application for wordpress?

Tags: customization

Is there os native application that makes possible to write and edit wordpress on a server?

I'm thinking about something like a `Evernote`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of tons of Weblog Clients compatible with WordPress.
[Click Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Weblog_Client)

If you're on Windows, I know alot of people liked Zoundry.